# How to write ruby function to check for case insensitive word "error" in a file and return a property

Tags: ruby, function, file, grep, line

The function written by me is given below. Will it work properly? else please correct me.

```
def log_file( file )  
    parsed_data = {}  
    read_lines( file ) {|line|  
        if line.match(/error/i)  
            parsed_data[:property] = "error"  
        end  
    }  
    return parsed_data  
end
```

Comment: Let's do it the other way round: ask a question if it doesn't work properly. Else don't.

Comment: @Stefan sorry. I am new to ruby coding. I tried to execute it in irb terminal.  I am not able to verify it because i am working just in this part of code. So my doubt is whether it will return the value as intended.

Comment: The method looks self-contained and possible to test in irb (except for `read_lines` method, but you can cut&paste that into irb, or just load your source file there e.g. `load foo.rb`). What is preventing you verifying it? Do you have any example inputs with expected outputs?

Comment: NeilSlater I am working on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The function **may** work properly, but it's impossible to tell as you're using methods defined externally such as `read_lines`.

Also, it's not very idiomatic Ruby (especially for the explicit return and the multi-line `{}` block).

Here's a possible alternative

```
def def log_file(file)
  File.open(file).each_line do |line|
    return({ property: "error" }) if line =~ /error/i
  end
  {}
end
```

Also, it doesn't really make a lot of sense to me to return a Hash, given the "error" string is hard-coded. Simply return "error" or nil.

```
def log_file(file)
  File.open(file).each_line do |line|
    return "error" if line =~ /error/i
  end
  nil
end
```

Or true/false

```
def success?(file)
  File.open(file).each_line do |line|
    return false if line =~ /error/i
  end
end

if success?(file)
  # no error
else
  # error
end
```